# Dynamic image serving using Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, proxy, google-cloud-storage

My application has a substantial number of images hosted on my local server, but I'm in the process of migrating to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). I've implemented a method to upload images to GCS, but now I need to adjust how these images are accessed in my Laravel application.

In Laravel, the asset method is extensively used to retrieve files. Changing this method globally can be time-consuming. Additionally, some parts of the application use the url method, while others access images directly from the database.

My approach involves updating the Nginx configuration to dynamically serve images from GCS if available, and fall back to the local server if necessary.

Here's my current Nginx configuration:

```
# ... other config

location ~ ^/files/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
    set $bucket_name my_bucket;
    set $gcs_path "https://storage.googleapis.com/$bucket_name/files/$1/$2";

    # Serve the file from GCS if it exists there
    proxy_pass $gcs_path;

    # Use @fallback location if GCS returns a 404
    error_page 404 = @fallback;
}

# Define the @fallback location to serve from the local server
location @fallback {
    rewrite ^/files/(\d+)/(.*)$ files/$1/$2 last; # Serve locally if not found in GCS
}

# ... other config
```

However, after applying this configuration, the images are still not being served dynamically.

> If anyone has an alternative solution or insights into why my approach might not be working, I'd greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
location ~ ^/files/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
        # If the file doesn't exist locally, try GCS or another location
        try_files $uri @fallback;
}
   
location @fallback {
        # handle fallback message
        set $bucket_name my_bucket;
        set $gcs_path "https://storage.googleapis.com/$bucket_name$uri";


        # Try serving the file from GCS first, and fallback to local if not found
        rewrite ^/files/(\d+)/(.*)$ $gcs_path redirect;
}
```